# Gitlab CI Web Deployment

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

So we are currently moving away from our current deployment provider: Beanstalk, which is great but we are on the top tier and we keep running out of space or hitting our repository limits. So we are moving away so please do not suggest any other SaaS provider.

I personally use Gitlab for my own projects and a few company projects and it's amazing we use a self hosted version on our local server in our company building.

We have CI setup and currently are using the following deployment code (I have minified the bits just to the deployment for development) - this uses the shell executer for deploying as we deploy to an existing linux server.

```
variables:
  HOSTNAME: '<hostname>'
  USERNAME: '<username>'
  PASSWORD: '<password>'
  PATH_DEV: '/path/to/www'

# Define the stages (we can add as many as we want)
stages:
  # - build
  - deploy

# The code for development deployment
deploy_dev:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploying to development environment..."
    - rm .gitlab-ci.yml
    - rsync -urltvz --filter=':- .gitignore' --exclude=".git" -e "sshpass -p"$PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" * $USERNAME@$HOSTNAME:$PATH_DEV
    - echo "Finished deploying."
  environment:
    name: Development
    url: http://dev.domain.com
  only:
    - envdev
```

**The Problem:**

When we use the above code to deploy it's perfect and works really well, and it deploys all the code after optimisation etc, but we have found a little bug here.

When you delete a file then the rsync command will not delete the file, now I did some searching and found the --remove flag you can add, and it worked - but it deleted all the user uploaded content as well. Now I added the .gitignore in to the filtering, so it would ignore some the files in their (which are usually user generated) or configuration files or/and libraries (npm, etc.). This is fine until a user started uploading files using the media manager in our framework which stores in a folder that is not in the .gitignore file and it can't because it contains other files, as we also add our own files in there so they're editable by the user, so now I am unsure how to manage this.

What we are looking for is a CI setup, which will upload file changes to the server, so it would search through the latest commits, and find the latest files that have been changed and then push only them files up. Of course I would like to do this with the Gitlab CI still, so any ideas examples or tutorials would be amazing.

Thanks in advance.

~ Danny

Answer (score -1):

May it helps: https://github.com/banago/PHPloy
Looks this tool designed for php project, but I think it can use other web deployment.

how it works:
PHPloy stores a file called .revision on your server. This file contains the hash of the commit that you have deployed to that server. When you run phploy, it downloads that file and compares the commit reference in it with the commit you are trying to deploy to find out which files to upload. PHPloy also stores a .revision file for each submodule in your repository.